# Cypress clock function makes html body invisible

Tags: javascript, css, testing, cypress, cypress-clock

in my cypress tests, I am looking to set the clock to a specific time to have a consistent time frame for every test.

When I call:

```js
cy.visit('/path/to/page');
cy.get('#elementId').click();
```

All is fine.

However, when I do:

```js
cy.clock(Date.now());
cy.visit('/path/to/page');
cy.get('#elementId').click();
```

I get the following error:

> ```
> This element `<button with Id i want to click>` is not visible 
> because its parent `<body>` has CSS property: `display: none`
> ```

This also happens when I pass no arguments to `cy.clock()`.
Why is `cy.clock()` setting the body of this page to invisible? And how do I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cy.clock()` command overwrites and freezes the javascript functions relating to timers - setTimeout, setInterval as well as the Date objects.

It looks like your app makes use of setTimeout during loading and some initial javascript is not completed.

Try adding a `cy.tick()` to the command sequence

```js
cy.clock(Date.now());
cy.visit('/path/to/page');
cy.tick(1000);                 // try longer and shorter timings
cy.get('#elementId').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you provide a custom out for the element to be visible first and then `click()`.

```js
cy.get('#elementId', {timeout: 6000}).should('be.visible').click()
```

Or, You can also use `{force: true}` in case you want to click a hidden element.

```js
cy.get('#elementId', {timeout: 6000}).should('be.visible').click({force: true})
```